# Django template's multiline string variable

Tags: javascript, django

At the begining of launching my app I am getting variables through django templates variables like so:

```
var my_variable = '{{ variable }}';
```

But sometimes it takes more than one line and provide a syntax error

```
var my_variable = "This should be a good variable;
But it isn't";
```

How to avoid `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this solution

```
<script>
    {% autoescape off %}
    var my_variable = "{{ variable|escapejs }}"
    {% endautoescape %}
</script>
```

[escapejs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)